# ERROR: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm getting an error from my SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         p.ItemGroupName, p.Varenummer, s.EAN, s.inventoryQuantity 
      FROM 
        ShopInventory s, ProductData p
     WHERE s.EAN = p.EAN
) 
ORDER BY cast(inventoryQuantity AS int) DESC
```

> `ERROR: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: A shot into the dark, the from clausel from first select query is missing, or the order by clausel must be put into the braces.

Comment: [mre] A subquery needs an alias in standard SQL.

Comment: Please use JOIN.

Comment: they dont have to use JOIN if they dont want to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably, you just need to give the subquery an alias:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         p.ItemGroupName, p.Varenummer, s.EAN, s.inventoryQuantity 
      FROM 
        ShopInventory s, ProductData p
     WHERE s.EAN = p.EAN
) mytable
ORDER BY cast(inventoryQuantity AS int) DESC
```

Some would say you are using the old join syntax instead of the recommended JOIN clause but for the purposes of solving your question I think thats a bit of a distraction. If you're interested in INNER JOIN , OUTER JOIN and all that you can read up here: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: This does sort of fix it, however, i would like for there not to be replicas of p.itemgroupname and p.varenummer and so on, i thought distinct would remove that, but it doesnt seem to do that

Comment: The distinct would be accross all four fields, is that what you're getting? i.e. each combination of ItemGroupName, Varenummer, EAN and inventoryquantity should only occur once

Comment: No, right now the only distinct element seems to be s.EAN but the 3 other fields arent distinct

Comment: @AndreasRavnholt Ask a new (specific researched non-duplicate on-topic) question in a new post. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Distinct might not be what you needed. You might want to SUM the inventoryQuantity over one or more of the other fields.